# Transfer data from Dynamodb to Redshift using Dynamodb stream but gettting NULL in redshift table

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

**Problem Statement**

I want to transfer data from DynamoDB to Redshift Table using DynamoDB Stream, lambda Function, and Kinesis Delivery Firehose.

I have a DynamoDB **profile** table to store the below data

```
{ Id": { "S": "108" }, "Name": {  "S": "Smith" },  
"Address": { "M": {  "City":{ "S": "California" },
"State":{ "S": "New York" },
"Country":{  "S": "USA"  } } },  
"Email": {  "S": "xyz2dffd@gmail.com"   },  "Designation": {  "S": "Sr.Dev" },  
"PhoneNumber": {     "S": "2124141241"   } }
```

I have a redshift table profile with schema

```
PROFILE ( Id varchar(255), Name varchar(255),
Address SUPER,   Email varchar(255),
Designation varchar(255),PhoneNumber varchar(255) );
```

I have a lambda function

```
import json
import boto3

firehose = boto3.client('firehose')
deliveryStreamName = 'Delivery Stream Name'

def convertToFirehoseRecord(ddbRecord):
    newImage = ddbRecord['NewImage']
    address = newImage.get('Address', {}).get('M', {})
    firehoseRecord = {
        "Id": newImage.get('Id', {}).get('S'),
        "Name": newImage.get('Name', {}).get('S'),
        "Address": {
            "State": address.get('State', {}).get('S'),
            "Country": address.get('Country', {}).get('S'),
            "City": address.get('City', {}).get('S')
        },
        "Email": newImage.get('Email', {}).get('S'),
        "Designation": newImage.get('Designation', {}).get('S'),
        "PhoneNumber": newImage.get('PhoneNumber', {}).get('S')
    }
    return firehoseRecord

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    firehoseRecords = []
    for record in event['Records']:
        print(record)
        ddbRecord = record['dynamodb']
        print('DDB Record: ' + json.dumps(ddbRecord))
        
        firehoseRecord = convertToFirehoseRecord(ddbRecord)
        print('Firehose Record: ' + json.dumps(firehoseRecord))
        
        firehoseRecords.append({'Data': json.dumps(firehoseRecord)})
    print('list')
    print(firehoseRecords)
    result = firehose.put_record_batch(DeliveryStreamName=deliveryStreamName, Records=firehoseRecords)
    print(result)
    return 'processed {} records.'.format(len(event['Records']))
```

Lambda is running fine.
[image: Lmabda Log]

I am using the below copy command in the delivery firehose stream

COPY profile FROM 's3://my-bucket/<manifest>' CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>' MANIFEST json 'auto';

Now the problem is everything is working but Redshift table is populated with NULL data for each column
[image: Image from Redshift Table]

> Note: Suggestion for python code or Node.js/Javascript code is also accepted.

Comment: Have you checked stl_load_errors for the status of the COPY command?  Have you checked that the manifest points to the correct S3 files? That the S3 json files are as you expect?

Comment: Hi @BillWeiner, Yes I checked stl_load_errors there is no error, and also manifests pointing to the correct S3 file where my JSON data is present.

Comment: OK good.  Check stl_load_commits and make sure that the files are being read.  I expect so but cover the bases.  The next likely possibilities is that Redshift couldn’t automatically match up columns and since the json has capital letters for fields.  Redshift uses lower case column names by default.  You may need a json_paths file to ensure that things match up or lower case field names in the json.  If that isn’t it I’d look to make sure the results of the COPY are being committed but I think Firehose takes care of this but worth a check - stl_commit_stats - you will need to line up the xid

Comment: Thank You @BillWeiner, It Works actually the issue was capital letters in json. Now I am getting data in Redshift. THANK YOU AGAIN.